# Setting function decrement in variable onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

Please.. i need a help with this thing..
I wanna use a variable ID in HTML, to call a function in javascript page.

Example:
html

(MINUS BUTTON DONT WORK)

```
<button class="minus-button quantity-button button" type="button" name="subtract" onclick="javascript: subtractDiv2(document.getElementById('<ccom:field id='Code' />'));" value="-">&nbsp;</button>
```

(THIS INPUT QUANTITY WORKS NORMAL)

```
 <input class="quantity-input" value="<ccom:field id="Qtd"/>" maxlength="3" id='<ccom:field id="Code" />' name="div2" onkeypress="return somenteNumerico(event);"/>
```

(PLUS BUTTON WORKS NORMAL)

```
<button class="plus-button quantity-button button" type="button" name="add" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('<ccom:field id='Code' />').value++;" value="+"></button>
```

javapage

```
function subtractDiv2(){
            if(value - 1 < 0)
                return;
            else
                 value--;
        };
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need `javascript:` in `onclick` attributes. That's only needed in `href`, to distinguish it from normal URLs.

Comment: Please give full explanation of what you expect this to do. Broken code isn't a substitute for a proper explanation

Comment: Off topic but inline events is a bad practice. Use addEventListener()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the argument to the function. It should be:

```
function subtractDiv2(div) {
    var value = parseInt(div.value, 10);
    if (value < 1) {
        return;
    } else {
        div.value = value - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanksss for helping.